# How would I run my code without revealing it to the user?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been working on Java and I am wondering how could I restrict people from accessing my code?

Is user-authorizing all classes (except driver) good enough? Or am I required to take further steps?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The source code, the byte code, or both?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: you can create a webservice, run that on a server you control, and only distribute a client which consumes (interacts with) that service. they might get access to the code of the client, but that's just a 'front'. they won't get to the code of the service.

Comment: @Stultuske or you may be working with standalone applications distributed in form of jars. Just obfuscate the code and provide the compiled bytecode (.class) files. This is, assuming this is what OP's looking for.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: indeed, but that will still be decompilable (even though if it takes a bit more effort than a simple compiled pojo)

Comment: @Stultuske have you tried reading through obfuscated code? :)

Comment: do I need to? :) does a compiler 'understand' what it compiles? nope, neither does a de-compiler. they just follow rules. sooner or later there'll be decompilers that 'guess' for meaning of obfuscated code, and compare those guesses to 'compilable or not'.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the more advanced Java bytecode obfuscators do much more than just class name mangling. [Zelix KlassMaster](http://www.zelix.com/), for example, can also scramble your code flow in a way that makes it really hard to follow and works as an excellent code optimizer...

Also many of the obfuscators are also able to scramble your string constants and remove unused code.

Another possible solution (not necessarily excluding the obfuscation) is to use encrypted JAR files and a custom classloader that does the decryption (preferably using native runtime library).